# MLFLOW Artifacts stored on ftp server but not showing in ui

Tags: python, machine-learning, ftp, pytorch, mlflow

I use MLFLOW to store some parameters and metrics during training on a remote tracking server. Now I tried to also add a .png file as an artifact, but since the MLFLOW server is running remotely I store the file on a ftp server. I gave the ftp server address and path to MLFLOW by:

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.sqlite --default-artifact-root ftp://user:password@1.2.3.4/artifacts/ --host 0.0.0.0 &
```

Now I train a network and store the artifact by running:

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(remote_server_uri)
mlflow.set_experiment("default")
mlflow.pytorch.autolog()

with mlflow.start_run():
    mlflow.log_params(flow_params)
    trainer.fit(model)
    trainer.test()
    mlflow.log_artifact("confusion_matrix.png")
mlflow.end_run()
```

I save the .png file locally and then log it with `mlflow.log_artifact("confusion_matrix.png")` to the ftp server in the right folder corresponding to the experiment. Everything works so far, only that the artifact does not show up in the mlflow ui online. The logged parameters and metrics show up normally. The artifact panel stays empty and only shows

```
No Artifacts Recorded
Use the log artifact APIs to store file outputs from MLflow runs.
```

I found similar threads, but only of users having the same problem on local mlflow storages. Unfortunately, I could not apply these fixes to my problem. Somebody has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: How did you confirm that `log_artifact()` worked correctly? Did you confirm that the file exists on the FTP server?

Comment: Exactly and that it is in the folder corresponding to the current run.

Comment: absolute wild guess, but: I have set up MLFLOW on your company kubernetes cluster with a Minio S3 Storage as backend-store and a postgres database for metrics. What I have found is that MLFlow does not come with the needed dependencies (and tells you nowhere what is needed). The only way to find out is by weird errors. Maybe this is what is happening here (although there probably should be some kind of `ModuleNotFoundError`, I guess)

Comment: i had the same problem and i struggled days before noticing that the s3 bucket endpoint url set in the mlflow configuration was different from the one i was using in my application.

Answer (score -3):

```
from ftplib import FTP
import mlflow

ftp_server = "your_server"
ftp_username = "your_username"
ftp_password = "your_password"
ftp_artifact_path = "path/to/artifact"

def check_artifact_path():
    try:
        with FTP(ftp_server) as ftp:
            ftp.login(ftp_username, ftp_password)
            ftp.cwd(ftp_artifact_path)
            print("Checking artifact path... Success")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Checking artifact path... Failed - {str(e)}")

def verify_ftp_connection():
    try:
        with FTP(ftp_server) as ftp:
            ftp.login(ftp_username, ftp_password)
            print("Verifying FTP server connection... Success")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Verifying FTP server connection... Failed - {str(e)}")

def check_mlflow_version():
    try:
        mlflow_version = mlflow.__version__
        print(f"Checking MLflow version... Version: {mlflow_version}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Checking MLflow version... Failed - {str(e)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_artifact_path()
    verify_ftp_connection()
    check_mlflow_version()

    print("Script execution complete.")
```

Dis Python sript is like ur tech buddie, makin' sure everythin's on point for usin' MLflow with an FTP server. First, it checks if it can smoothly connek to the FTP server usin' the provided info. Then, it makes sure the specfied artifact path on the server is good to go. Finally, it checks and prints the MLflow libary version to make sure it's all compatibul.

Aftr each check, it gives ya the lowdown on success or any hiccups. In a nutshell, this script ensures everythin's set up right for loggin' MLflow artifacts onto that FTP server. It's yer go-to helpa in the tech journey!

you can run powershell script to check its working flow and will address probable error u facing

```
# Replace these with your actual values
$mlflowServerUri = "http://your-mlflow-server-uri"
$experimentName = "default"
$runId = "your-run-id"

# Checking out your runs...
$runs = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$mlflowServerUri/api/2.0/mlflow/runs/list?experiment_id=$experimentName" -Method Get

# Checking the deets of your run...
$run = $runs.data | Where-Object { $_.info.run_id -eq $runId }
if ($run) {
    Write-Host "here's the scoop on your run:"
    Write-Host "Run ID: $($run.info.run_id)"
    Write-Host "Status: $($run.info.status)"
    Write-Host "Started at: $($run.info.start_time)"
    Write-Host "Ended at: $($run.info.end_time)"
    
    # Now, let's peek at the artifacts...
    $artifacts = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$mlflowServerUri/api/2.0/mlflow/artifacts/list?run_id=$runId" -Method Get
    Write-Host "`nArtifacts in the spotlight:"
    foreach ($artifact in $artifacts.data) {
        Write-Host "Artifact Path: $($artifact.info.path)"
        Write-Host "Artifact Size: $($artifact.info.file_size)"
        Write-Host "Last Modified: $($artifact.info.mtime)"
        Write-Host "Artifact URI: $($artifact.info.artifact_uri)"
        Write-Host "View it here: $($artifact.info.view_uri)`n"
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Hmm, can't find a run with ID $runId in the $experimentName experiment. Check your IDs!"
}
```